# Espaço entre divs desnecessario

Tags: html, css

Boas, eu estava a criar duas divs quando me deparei com este espaço... já estive a procura pelo código todo algo que esteja a criar esse espaço mas nao encontro, supostamente era para ele nem la estar...

Alguem sabe como posso remover esse espaço sem que tenha que dar margins negativas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body {
    font-family: arial;
}

.menu-principal {
    background-color: #ababab;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo img {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.logo {
    display: inline;
}

main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
    position: relative;
}

.redes-sociais {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
}

.redes-sociais li {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.redes-sociais li img {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu-secundario {
    background-color: #7fd0ff;
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
}

.menu-secundario li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

a:visited {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Rio Lis</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/normalize.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="menu-principal">
        <main>
            <div class="header-1">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="../html/index.html"><img src="../img/logo.png" height="50px" width="auto"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="redes-sociais">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="../img/face-logo.png" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="../img/insta-logo.png" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="../img/twitter-logo.png" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com"><img src="../img/youtube-logo.png" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="menu-secundario">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Historias</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Linha temporal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Impacto da poluição</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Percurso</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Jogo</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </main>
    </header>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tente dar uma altura para o `header-1`, veja se isto soluciona o seu problema

Comment: no exemplo que colocou aqui não aparece esse espaço :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual mas aparece com esta na imagem e eu nao sei como resolver porque não é suposto ter o espaço, é suposto estár como está no exemplo

Comment: eu percebi pela imagem, mas é difícil dizer o que possa ser sem ver acontecer, se conseguisse replicar o problema aqui seria mais fácil

Comment: Provavelmente está aparecendo este espaço porque uma imagem ou mais está sobrepondo o tamanho da `div class="header-1"`

Comment: @JaksonFischer era a imagen dos logos das redes sociais obrigado!!

Comment: @DavidMv, opa, que bom que tu conseguiste consertar :D

Answer (score 0):

Cara, você precisa remover a margem superior padrão que as `ul` possuem, assim você não vai precisar fazer a gambiara de usar uma margem negativa nas imagens das redes sociais puxando elas pra cima.

Um dos motivos que estão gerando o espaço entre os elementos é exatamente a margem superior da `ul` dentro da div azul, e também não use `float: left` nas suas `li`'s. Em vez disso use flexbox na `ul` com `display: flex` para que as `li`'s fiquem alinhadas na horizontal.

Veja no exemplo abaixo como fica e observe os comentários do CSS do que foi removido e acrescentado:

```css
body {
    font-family: arial;
}

.menu-principal {
    background-color: #ababab;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo img {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.logo {
    display: inline;
}

main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
    position: relative;
}

.redes-sociais {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
}

.redes-sociais li {
    float: left;
    /* margin-top: -12px; REMOVIDO */
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.redes-sociais li img {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 0; /* ADICIONADO */
}

.menu-secundario {
    background-color: #7fd0ff;
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
}

/* ADICIONADO */
.menu-secundario nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-secundario li {
    /* float: left; REMOVIDO */
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

a:visited {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Rio Lis</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/normalize.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="menu-principal">
        <main>
            <div class="header-1">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="../html/index.html"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" height="50px" width="auto"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="redes-sociais">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="menu-secundario">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Historias</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Linha temporal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Impacto da poluição</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Percurso</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Jogo</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </main>
    </header>


</body>

</html>
```